# WSO2 ESB and JMSBytes/JMSText messages

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq, mq, mtom, wso2-esb

We have a WSO2ESB-based solution using WebSphere MQ as a transport. We have a number of client applications (.Net-based, Java MQI, JMS) which are creating and sending messages to WSO2ESB.
By default all of the messages are handled as JMSTextMessage but for our services we need to process messages as a JMSBytesMessage (we use MTOM messages over JMS). 
We don't have any abilities to change client applications so we need a 'hack' on WSO2ESB side to handle these messages correct.

Are there any features or hacks in WSO2ESB that could help us?